# Loading Gmail in Tor

Tags: socks, torsocks

When using Gmail in Firefox Google Chat works fine but when Gmail is accessed through Tor, the chat doesn’t load. Moreover, it says "Authentication Problem" and request to log in again in a red line on top of Gmail.

However it is possible to  keep on using Gmail despite of the annoying notification in red.

I would be thrilled to know as to why the Google chat on the left hand side of Gmail loads when using the Tor proxy 127.0.0.1 PORT 9150 on Firefox but never loads on Tor browser.

Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TBB is a Firefox ESR with some configuration changes that make it more 'anonymous'

this is from the web:

"...Also, note that the Firefox ESR in our bundles is [modified](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torbrowser.git/tree/HEAD:/build-scripts/config/) from the [default Firefox ESR](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/organizations/) "

It also could be an add-on, usually Tor´s browser has enable "noScript", disable it and try again.

Comment: Alternatively, instead of disabling noscript, try connecting with a general purpose XMPP client (eg. Gajim or Pidgin) using Tor as a SOCKS5 proxy.